# Add Custom Operation to different Group in ApiPlatform docs

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have a custom Operation `CreatePerson` which is dispatched via `messenger`.

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     messenger=true,
 *     output=false,
 *     shortName="person",
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "post"
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={}
 * )
 *
 * @psalm-immutable
 */
final class CreatePerson
```

This works as expected with `POST /api/people` (people instead of person because ApiPlatform uses Inflection to pluralize the `shortname` on `collectionOperations`.

The API-Docs look like that:

[image]

I'd like to add a list of persons, too.
So I created an other Api-Resource:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get"
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={}
 * )
 *
 * @psalm-immutable
 */
final class Person
```

The `shortname` of my `customOperation` ist `person`. This is also the group in the docs I want my `list` operation in.

Everything works as expected. `Person` and `CreatePerson` are two `ApiResource`s.
But now my docs look like that:

[image]

**I want to group them both together in the API-Docs (because they belong together).**

The reason why I use an extra `CreatePerson`-DTO here is because I
use Api-Platform completely without doctrine. The DTO gets dispatched through messenger and creates a Person via Event-Sourcing.
The `Person`-class is a readonly projection.

Comment: I don't understand. The command is `CreatePerson`. But the error message points to `App\Entity\Person`. Not possible to answer with this amount of detail. It is entirely possible to add custom operations this way (dto + messenger), so something else is amiss in your setup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to clarify my question.

Comment: Yeah, but the clarification does not really clear things up for me. The previous revision had a configuration that seemed OK, but an error message that was not consistent with that configuration. I could answer this revision, but in the end I would just be repeating the configuration you had in the previous revision. Sorry.

Comment: The previous revision was me trying to hack around the problem.
I found out why the group does not work as expected.

I had to change the `shortName="person"` to `shortName="Person"` and that's it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution for me was using `openapi_context`.

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     messenger=true,
 *     output=false,
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "post"={
 *              "method"="POST",
 *              "path"="/people",
 *              "openapi_context"={
 *                  "tags"={
 *                      "Person"
 *                  },
 *             },
 *         },
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={},
 * )
 *
 * @psalm-immutable
 */
final class CreatePerson
```

And `Person`:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "get"
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={},
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PersonRepository")
 *
 * @psalm-immutable
 */
final class Person
```

(seen here: https://github.com/api-platform/docs/issues/143)

With the following result in the docs:

[image]